# udev rules exclude device

Tags: linux, hard-drive, rules, udev

is it possible to use udev rules to excluce a single device from the rule?

for instance if I have 5 harddisk plugged in and I want to create custom names for all harddisk except for a single one? is it Possible?

Also, kernel names disks after sdz are named with 2 characters. sdaa,sdab, sdqr etc. I have a problem with it since I dont want to include the partition in sda1, sdb2 etc. can I wildcard all characters but not all numbers?

example:

```
KERNEL=="sd??",  NAME="test/Disk%n",  ATTRS{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}!="xxxx"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for instance if I have 5 harddisk plugged in and I want to create custom names for all harddisk except for a single one? is it Possible?

- You can use `GOTO` to skip rules:

  ```
  ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="xxxx|yyyy|zzzz", GOTO="custom_names_end"
  ENV{ID_MODEL}=="blahblah", GOTO="custom_names_end"

  KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", SYMLINK+="test/Disk%n"

  LABEL="custom_names_end"
  ```
- Note that `ID_SERIAL_SHORT` is not an attribute; it's an udev "environment" variable, so you need to use `ENV{}` or `ENVS{}` to match it. Attributes are read from sysfs directly.
- Also note that recent udev versions forbid renaming devices; you can only add custom symlinks.

> Also, kernel names disks after sdz are named with 2 characters. sdaa,sdab, sdqr etc. I have a problem with it since I dont want to include the partition in sda1, sdb2 etc. can I wildcard all characters but not all numbers?

- You're using the wrong approach. If you want to match disks but not partitions, then **do exactly that**:

  ```
  KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", …
  ```

  The `DEVTYPE` values can be seen in `udevadm info /dev/sda` and `udevadm info /dev/sda1`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It triggers, but only on the first disk it finds. so I only have a single symlink in /dev/test Also is it possible to use numbering as the last digit? so the first device it finds is Disk0 then Disk1 etc?

Comment: @prgmjunkie: Try manually running it on other devices using `udevadm test` or `udevadm trigger`.

Comment: it trigger but the %n operator in the symlink declaration seems to not work correctly the device symlink is always called Disk with nothing appended.

Comment: If I use %k instead of %n it works.

Comment: It could be that udev just doesn't know how to assign numbers to sd* devices... (Personally I think %n is quite useless anyway, as device order is unstable. Better use UUIDs like in /dev/disk/by-uuid/…)